# Chrome dev won't map file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The sources are server by a tomcat server using springboot, using localhost:8000
I have added the local source folder to the workspace, I am asked the question to map the network resource 
[image]
But the question keeps on coming and I'm unable to make a persistent mapping.

I have also tried adding the path to the workspace folder, in that scenario I won't see my network files anymore, only the local files (hinting they are mapped correctly) but I'm unable to set breakpoints or change network files on the fly.

I've been working with it forever and suddenly it just won't work. Anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was that all the files had an extra "?" at the end of the url, because require.js was configured with urlArgs: "", which didn't add any params but added the question mark, I changed the configuration to urlArgs: null and that fixed it.